# Laravel and swiftmailer auth_mode

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, swiftmailer

How can I specify

```
`'auth_mode' => 'login'`
```

for swiftmailer using Laravel mail configuration? Looks like without this parameter yandex mail doesn't work. But I can't find such parameter in config/mail.php

Comment: Did you able to achieve this? We need to configure the auth_mode to 'plain'. We are using laravel 5.4 and swiftmailer. We searched everywhere with no possible options for the same.

Answer (score 0):

you may try swift mailer Instance this way:: you need to add `swiftmailer`  in composer.json file in require sectio such as :

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "@stable"
},
```

then update composer

```
composer update
```

usage of swift mailer in controller ::

```
use Swift_Transport;
use Swift_Message;
use Swift_Mailer;

class Mailer
{

public function send_mail(){

    // Create the Transport
    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance($host, $port, 'ssl')
        ->setUsername($username)
        ->setPassword($password)
    ;
    // Send the email
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
    // Create the message
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance(null);
    $message->setTo($to_email);
    #$message->setCc("selimppc@gmail.com");
    $message->setSubject($subject);
    $message->setBody($body);
    $message->setFrom($from_email, $from_name);
    $reply_to_name = 'Real World';
    $reply_to_name_arr = @explode('@', $reply_to);
    $reply_to_name = @$reply_to_name_arr[0];
    $message->setReplyTo($reply_to, $reply_to_name);
    $message->setReadReceiptTo("devdhaka404@gmail.com");
    //Bounce Email
    $message->setReturnPath($reply_to);

 }
}
```

This will help you lot. Thank you so much